# How to magnify in Chrome without scaling the page?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

How do I magnify/zoom in the page in Chrome without changing the scale of the page. The built-in `Ctrl`,`+` and `Ctrl`,`-` change the scale of the page to provide the zoom effect, but I only want to magnify the page without affecting the scale.

On laptops and phones you can use pinch/expand gestures to change magnification. (Unless restricted via the *viewport* meta tag.) So I know it's possible to magnify, but how do I do it on PC where I don't have a touch pad to recognize gestures?

Comment: Wrong : The pinch/expand gestures do change the scaling of the entire page.

Comment: Then what is the term I was suppose to use? If I use shortcuts on PC, the page doesn't zoom, it's like it reduces the size of the viewport so that everything has to become bigger. I don't want that, instead I want to change the zoom/magnification without changing the viewport. I hope that clears up some confusion.

Comment: It seems that this gesture zoom feature is exclusively accessible if you have a touchpad that recognizes pinch/expand gestures.

Seems like I'll have to create an extension for this, because the existing ones aren't really what I'm looking for. I want to be able to zoom in easily, preferably while holding `Alt` and then zooming in/out and moving the screen, similar to Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: adobe illustrator is able to achieve the zoom that you are talking about because the image is generated mathematically ... chrome can do it if you are viewing an SVG image, which is practically the same as pdf

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and after a bit of searching found [Mouse Pinch-To-Zoom](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/mouse-pinch-to-zoom/pffiadlahfhoniddbipeiiohjnlongfi?hl=en) extension. Mouse Pinch-To-Zoom keeps text and svgs sharp and has decent customization. Other options I tried blurred everything to hell and back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Windows PC, then use the magnifier. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to turn it on, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> to turn it off.

Note that it works globally not just Chrome.

OR

You can install [Magnifying Glass (Hover Zoom)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magnifying-glass-hover-zo/gfcbebjdigncefnokoncehghgfndjcgn/related?hl=en) an extension

> that enables you to magnify a portion of a webpage with click of a button.
> Press on the toolbar button to see the magnifying glass on the current page.

[image: Screen while using Magnifier Glass]

Comment: Although your answer is useful, it's not the solution I'm looking for. I was thinking there was a way to zoom in just like on phones or laptops, without losing quality. The magnifier zoom is a raster zoom, so it loses quality. Regarding the extension, it's also a magnifier tool, which is not really what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Try this software: [Glassbrick](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/glassbrick-screen-magnifier/9N1WPWBLXWWK?hl=en-us&gl=US).

With this, you can magnify your entire screen by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd> with your mouse wheel. You can also re-map the keys to something else like <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or some other combination of those.

Seems to work nicely, and its free.